# C# 'System.StackOverflowException' in InitializeComponent()

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

Here are the main parts of the program where the exception seems to be concerned.

```
using System.Drawing;
using Framework.pages;

namespace Framework
{
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
       public string status;
       public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent(); // Unhandled exception here
           InitializeTheme();

           activationStep page = new activationStep();
           page.loadPage();
       }
       // etc etc
```

This is the abstract class

```
 namespace Framework.pages
 {
     abstract class template : MainWindow
     { 
         public abstract void loadPage();
         public abstract void loadTheme();
     }
 }
```

This is the activation step class

```
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Framework.pages
{
    class activationStep : template
    {
        public override void loadPage()
        {
            //this.loadTheme();
        }

        public override void loadTheme()
        {
            // Default green activation button
            //activateButton.Background = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(Framework.theme.darkGreen);
            //activateButton.BorderBrush = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(Framework.theme.borderGreen);
            // Set form error color to red
            //activationFormError.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
        }
        // etc etc
```

The thing is if I comment out these two lines from the MainWindow class:

```
activationStep page = new activationStep();
page.loadPage();
```

The program runs fine despite the fact that everything within the activationStep class is commented out anyway (even if they aren't commented out too)? I'm just completely clueless as to why I'm getting this particular exception as there definitely doesn't seem to be any intense loops or anything.

-It's worth noting that there really are not many components loaded into the form and it runs smoothly usually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're "newing" up an `activationStep`, which derives from `template`, which in turn derives from `MainWindow`, whose constructor creates a new `activationStep`... etc, etc.

This loop runs for awhile, and then you get a `StackOverflowException`.

You'll need to rethink your design.

Comment: Ah i see, I didn't really expect it go on for an infinite loop though? but anyhow I guess the recommendation is to rewrite the entire thing. Thanks for the answer though, really appreciate it!

Comment: The problem is fixed completely now.